# Link Paypal payment to asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, paypal-sandbox, website-payment-pro

I'm trying to link my asp.net website to Paypal payment system..
I had created my business profile on Paypal and add paypal buttons to my web page but I can't understand how to make Paypal reference the information.. 
any one have idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For paypal integration, you need to do implement the code, Here I put the  SDK and Rest Api link take look into:

1. Visit https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks
2. Visit https://developer.paypal.com/reference/